# Why the CatalogSearch is not installing during the integration test?

Tags: magento2, testing, integration

I'm trying to run my Integration test on magento2 but keep getting the same error.

> Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
>   Installing data...

[Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Scope\IndexTableNotExistException]
  Temporary table for index catalogsearch_fulltext doesn't exist, which is inconsistent with state of scope resolver

```
Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Scope/IndexSwitcher.php:58
 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Scope\IndexSwitcher->switchIndex() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/IndexSwitcherProxy.php:79
 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\IndexSwitcherProxy->switchIndex() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php:154
 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeFull() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php:412
 Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexAll() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php:248
 Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexAll() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Setup/InstallData.php:45
 Magento\CatalogSearch\Setup\InstallData->install() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:868
 Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:792
 Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:343
 Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install() at /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/InstallCommand.php:146
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:843
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:104
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento:23
```

I've tried the following:

```
rm -rf vendor/* composer.lock
composer update
composer upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush           
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But nothing worked.

I installed a clean magento2 setup and here It works.
But I can't figure out why al my custom code from `app/code/{myvendor}` from the original project was copied to the fresh install and still it works on the fresh install.

Comment: I have the same error when installing Magento 2.2.5 clean

Comment: I also have this issue, have you found any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to the elastic search indexer in magento 2.

Elsatic search must be enabled to use it:

> Magento 2.3.1 adds support for Elasticsearch 6.x and it is enabled by
>   default. Magento still provides connectivity for Elasticsearch 2.x and
>   5.x but these must be enabled in order to use these versions. Elasticsearch 2.x is still supported but strongly discouraged. If you
>   must run Elasticsearch 2.x or 5.x with Magento 2.3.1, you must change
>   the Elasticsearch php client. Follow the instructions in Change
>   Elasticsearch Client.
>
> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

You may change to mysql indexer with the following command:

> php -f bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'mysql'

or change this value in the database.

Then, to list the search engine configured

> php -f bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine

Comment: Link is not answer if link is expired. So please describe it here.

Comment: Please review, i edited my  answer.

Comment: if you have any doubt. please visite https://magento.stackexchange.com/tour